# fill object data source with class in another project

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, objectdatasource

I'm quit new in c# and linq and I need to fill an ObjectDataSource (in vb.net) with code using a class in another project (in .c#).

I tried doing these things:
1. Add the reference
2. "Imports Project2" in the code behind page.
3. Fill in the load event:

```
Dim ObjectClass1 As New Class1(ConnectionString)

myODS.TypeName = "ObjectClass1"
myODS.SelectMethod = "GetData"
myODS.SelectParameters("Filter1Name") = New Parameter("Filter1Name", DbType.String, "xxx")
```

4. The class in the other project looks like this:

   ```
   public class Class1
      {
       public string ConnectionString { get; }

       public Class1(string connectionString)
       {
           ConnectionString = connectionString;
       }

       public IQueryable<MyObject> GetData(string Filter1Name)
         {
          using (MyObjectDataContext dataContext = new  MyObjectDataContext(ConnectionString))
             {
               var Result = dataContext.MyObject.Where(x => x.FILTER_1== Filter1Name).Select(x => new MyObject
                     {
                       Field1 = x.FIELD_1,
                       Field2 = x.FIELD_2
                     });
              return Result;
             }
           }
       }
   ```

And this is the error I get:
ObjectDataSource 'myODS' could not find a non-generic method 'GetData' that has parameters: Filter1Name

What this error means? Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: What `GetInfo` & `ObjectClass1` belongs to? Either you're using wrong type name, select method name or invalid arguments for `GetInfo`.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when I wrote the question here... GetInfo is GetData (The method in the Class1 class). 
And about the ObjectClass1 variable.... is the instance of Class1 in the page.

Answer (score 0):

It means it can't find a method on your class called `GetInfo()`
Looking at your class1 definition, you probably meant to make it `GetData`

Dim ObjectClass1 As New Class1(ConnectionString)

```
myODS.TypeName = "ObjectClass1"
myODS.SelectMethod = "GetData"
myODS.SelectParameters("Filter1Name") = New Parameter("Filter1Name", DbType.String, "xxx")
```

Comment: I made the mistake in this example but no in my code. Do you have any clue about the error?

Comment: @Melipao I think your `TypeName` is wrong. You are setting it as the name of the variable that holds the instance of `class1`. It should be the type which is class1 with the full namespace like `Samples.AspNet.CS.Class1`